# Iterating through specialCells range without memory leak?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have situation like this:

```
Range formulaCells = range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas);
```

And I want to iterate through all of them. But problem is when I do it with foreach loop memory leak happens since range object of particular cell isn't released.
I'm trying to do it by conventional for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= formulaCells.Count; i++)
{
  Range cell = null;
  try
  {
    cell = formulaCells.get_Item(i);
    // do some work
  }
  catch(Exception e) {throw e;}
  finally
  {
    If(cell != null)
    {
      Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(cell);
      cell = null;
    }
  }
}
```

But get_Item() takes row index as parameter, so it'll go through cells that doesn't have formula to. I cannot iterate with it.
How should I do this?

Comment: formulaCells is a Range, can't you index it directly? formulaCells[i]?

Comment: Also: what are you doing in `//some work`? Often loops over ranges can be replaced by direct assignments, like `range.Color = ...`. That way you can let excel do the work, which is usually faster.

Comment: Also when you say memory leak do you mean simply that you get an `Out of Memory` exception?

Comment: I need to remember address and value of every cell in this range. And after that I'll need to iterate through that collection and return values of only cells which are specific to me (have particular name pattern that I have assigned to them)

Comment: @Joshua Drake, no. I mean that every COM object should be released because it can cause Excel process hanging.

Comment: Are you trying to work in Excel directly while automating it?  Have you used a `using` statement?  Have you called the _Application.Quit Method?

Comment: @Joshua Drake, I'm working within Excel addin.

Comment: So, you go through the whole range at first, and then again through a subset of that range? Why not doing all the stuff at the first iteration?

Comment: @phg, The whole range is to large, like 10k cells, and I work with it with spreadsheet XML. But that format has limitation that can only recognize formulas in which referents are in this XML. That is why I need to do this part using interop.

Comment: @NominSim, formulaCells[i] is rowIndex based, so it'll return cell where i is it's rowIndex, if you have range with not consecutive cells you cannot use this approach. For example if formula cells are B1, B5, B17, if you iterate with formulaCells[i] you gain B1, B2, B3.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it looks like `formulaCells` is a list of cells that fall into the `SpecialCells` format `XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas` , you should be able to access each of these cells by indexing through the list i.e. `formulaCells[i]` NOT `formulaCells.get_item(i)`...

Comment: @NomimSim, Note that formulaCells[i] is the same as formulaCells.get_Item(i)

Comment: formulaCells is a list, if you are getting unexpected values when you iterate over them then you are creating the list inaccurately.

Comment: @NominSim, You are not right, forumlaCells is range as any other, check it out for your self. I'll just use foreach and hope that it won't make any memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use foreach with COM collections; internally, it creates a COM object. Use a for loop instead.

Vladimir, *formulaCells* contains multiple areas (Range.Areas), each area is a rectangle of the Excel.Range type. So you need to walk through all areas and through every cell of each area.

Comment: Smolin, I know that, I read some of your posts on add-in Express about that. But problem is that when I use for loop, I cannot iterate through collection since it will give me item consecutively in range. For example, If I have range A1:A8, and I find formula cells with SpecialCells and gain another range with A2, A5, A8. If I try this: formulaRange[i], I'll gain cells A2, A3 and A4. Since indexing is based on row index.